# Сигналы и слоты Qt как в них ориентироваться?

Tags: c++, qt, обработка-сигналов, сигналы-слоты, инструменты-разработчика

После того как мой проект начал разрастаться быстро отследить связи между сигналами и слотами становится затруднительно. Есть ли какие нибудь рекомендации для того чтобы удобно и быстро можно было отслеживать связи. На данный момент у меня только один вариант, записывать все связи на бумаге и постоянно их сверять в процессе разработки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Какие только возможно связи делать средствами дизайнера, чтобы не забивать ими исходники.
2. Массовое создание связей выносить в отдельный метод.
3. В этом методе группировать создание связей по источникам.
4. Обязательно проверять, что `connect` возвращает `TRUE`.
5. Использовать возможности C++11 для `connect()`, тогда проверка совместимости сигнала и слота будет происходить в момент компиляции.

Пример для 5-го пункта:

```
connect(sender, &Sender::valueChanged, receiver, &Receiver::updateValue );
```

[Документация](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax/ru)

Comment: Можно нагляднее в примерах, в частности про с++11? У меня на данный момент всё лежит в файле main.cpp

Comment: @shaman888, добавил.